# How to invite testers for betatesting in 2019 (Android)

Tags: android, beta-testing, google-console-developer

Seems google has changed the concept. In old days I could invite users to a google+ group and assign the group to the beta testers.

Actually as I saw I am only able to create an open beta test with at least 1000 users.

How can I test the app with only some specific users ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under "App releases" you can choose Alpha and then click on the arrow to the right of the text that says "Manage Testers" where you can add the emails of your test users.

It's easy to miss so here's a screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping. So the new concept is, that only in alpha test we test with specific users and in beta for a bigger audience.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play now uses the concept "open" and "closed" testing tracks, which you can create with whatever name you want. "Closed" tests are one with a limited number of named users. "Open" tests are ones where the users can opt-in themself in the Play Store. The [documentation explaining all this is here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213).